# Tomcat doesn't unload web app

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application running in Tomcat on Linux. My webapp uses a third party jar, and the jar uses a native library.

Whenever I redeploy my application, Tomcat notices the new war file and reloads my application. However, it apparently doesn't unload the previous version, and when I try to execute code that uses the jar, I get this error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /var/cache/tomcat7/temp/libaocr_x64.so already loaded in another classloader

If I restart the entire Tomcat process, I can clear the error, but I would prefer not to do that.

What is causing Tomcat to not release the old version of the app?

I'm aware that this kind of problem is sometimes caused by connection pools that have threads running to monitor connections -- I have a connection in my app, but I don't think it's configured to have this kind of thread running.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

JNI is so low-level that it is outside of Tomcats Container. Unfortunately You can not unload the librarys.

Try to put the jar into tomcat's endorsed-folder (`$CATALINA_HOME/commons/endorsed`) but it will be available for each app in the tomcat.